# I have error in java, when I select an entry from the Derby database

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

**this my SQL query**

```
"SELECT doctor.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.email,users.password, users.birthday,users.address,users.phone,users.role_id,doctor.id_type,specialty.name, count(patient.id)as count_patient"
            + "FROM  patient RIGHT JOIN users INNER JOIN doctor ON users.id=doctor.id "
            + "INNER JOIN  specialty ON specialty.id=doctor.id_type ON doctor.id =patient.id_doctor)"
            + "GROUP BY doctor.id,users.first_name,users.last_name,users.email,users.password,users.birthday,users.address,users.phone,users.role_id,doctor.id_type,specialty.name ORDER BY users.first_name";
```

**I have error on eclepse**

```
[ERROR]      DoctorDAO(sortByFirstName):185 - Syntax error: Encountered "patient" at line 1, column 204.
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "patient" at line 1, column 204.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)....
```

I know that the table was set and the 'SQL' query is executed in the  IJ console  derby.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a space in the statement: `count_patient" + "FROM` Failing that, I'd suggest printing the string and pasting that into your question.